# Esaiest way to Check if a Javascript variable's value is between several ranges?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

If a number should be tested against a few ranges of values, this works :

```
if ((number > a && number < b)||(number > b && number < d))
    {return true;}
    else {return false;}
```

This is handy for just 2 ranges,
but it is not very convenient if there are lots of ranges of values.

Any other option here ?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the ranges?

Comment: Loops can be handy here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement, for example:

```
switch (number) {
case (number > a && number < b):
case (number > b && number < d):
    return true;
default:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Switch statement looks perfect for that. Thx very much.

Comment: @AdrienLafond, A better way to say **Thanks** is to accept and upvote the answer!

Comment: It's not scalable though and does not return the same value as the example in the question.

Comment: Edited to do the same thing as the original post.

Comment: @RayonDabre : sure, but have to wait 10 minutes more ;)

Comment: Of course there can be more scalable solutions, especially by using functional programming, but I find this more readable.

Comment: but this look a like simple `if` if you format `if` in OP you get a same, but without `case` :-)

Comment: It does. But if you have, let's say, five cases in which you need to return true, the switch is more readable. Of course, for two cases, as in this example, I would not recommend this approach. OP himself said, "not very convenient if there are lots of ranges of values", and this solves exactly that.

Comment: @meskobalazs, yep :-) missing that, fix url above. So, methinks, this same or even more readable than `case`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: save ranges in array and check it in loop like this

```
var ranges = [[a,b],[c,d]]

var inRange = ranges.some(function(el){ return number > el[0] && number < el[1]})
```

here use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function, but it can be easy changed to simple loop.

```
function checkRange(ranges, value){
    for(var i=0, len=ranges.length; i<len; i++){
        if(value > ranges[0] && value < ranges[1]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and call it like `checkRange(ranges, number)`

Comment: I actually think yours is a good answer.  Kind of funny the switch statement 'won' the point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
function isBetween(number, low, high) {
    return number > low && number < high;
}
```

And then test easily:

```
return (isBetween(number, a, b) || isBetween(number, b, d))
```

Note that you don't need to return value in if-statement's branches, just return the condition value.

Comment: @AdrienLafond, but you use it in your own sample :-)

Comment: Interesting way to proceed. About your last note plz : how to return the condition value ?

Comment: Just as I wrote: `return (isBetween(number, a, b) || isBetween(number, b, d))` - this way you don't need to check if and then return `true` if the condition value is positive, but just return calculated condition.

Answer (score 0):

Write a couple of simple functions and you're done.

```
function inRangeInclusive(num, min, max) {
   return num >= min && num <= max;
}

function inRangeExclusive(num, min, max) {
   return num > min && num < max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let between = (n, n1, n2) => { return n >= n1 && n <= n2; }                                                                                                         

let inRanges = (num, ranges) => {                                                                                                                                   
  for (let range of ranges) {                                                                                                                                       
    if (between(num, range[0], range[1])) return true;                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                 
  return false;                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                   

console.log(inRanges(4, [[1,2], [5,10], [5, 6]]));
```

Comment: `let` and `arrow function` available not in all browsers :-)

Comment: so, you can add it to answer